# iPad generating pdf crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf-generation, core-graphics

I am trying to generate PDF reports with more than 300 pages from my app,but after long time the app is crashing without showing anything in the console, i am not getting memory warnings also, please help me to fix this issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of let me know ... what do you add in PDF.. i.e. can you add images ? or only text Please explain...if you can add images then it would be crash in 300 pages.. and it required Compress the image file size.. Let me know first of all..or possible to show your code.. i will help you...

Comment: Hello Suresh, Thanks for your idea. Each page will be having one image and text.

Comment: ok then you Compress the Image File size and let me know how much total pdf file size.? and try after compress the image.. Second thing you also want to release each pdf page..i.e. when you redirect from 1 to 2 page then release the memory of 1 page..

Comment: Hello Suresh, even after compressing the image also i could not fix the issue, i am running lot of loops and checking lot of conditions i think that may be the problem...

Comment: HI.. I also got the problem before few days in Ipad Pdf.. Use this code https://github.com/vfr/Reader/downloads may be it helps.. i done with that code. but i also compress the image file.. I save the Image in database.. so i compress at the time of saving..not the compress at the time of pdf generation. and i solve that issue...with compress image and run pdf in that code..IPad have run well ...But its not work in iPod ....... In iPod have i got the Memory warning and crash the app..

Comment: Hi suresh, is this for reading pdf? actually i want to generate pdf.

Comment: Yes first you generate the pdf and assign in the ReadearViewController

Comment: NSString *phrase = nil;  NSString *filePath = [self pdfPath]; //Document directory Path        
 ReaderDocument *document = [[[ReaderDocument alloc]initWithFilePath:filePath password:phrase] autorelease];
if (document != nil) {
ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
readerViewController.delegate = self;            
#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)
[self.navigationController pushViewController:readerViewController animated:YES]; #else // present in a modal view controller

Comment: readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
            
            [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
            
#endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
            
            [readerViewController release]; // Release the ReaderViewController
        }